# PDF Viewer app works fine on android 10 and below but keeps crashing on android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
    I am new to stackoverflow, android programming please forgive me if I make mistakes and I request the community to help me find the solution for this question.
    My PDF Viewer app keeps crashing on android 11 but works below android 11.
```

Please let me know whether I have written"asking the permission code" and "display pdf code" right or what needs to be changed.

```
    '''
    
     - Main Activity

package com.example.pdfreader;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.Acimport androidx.core.content.PackageManagerCompat;tivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPdfSelectListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(isPermissionGranted()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Already Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            takePermission();
        }
        displayPdf();

    }
    /*public void takePermissions(View view) {
        if(isPermissionGranted()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Already Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             displayPdf();
        }
    }*/

        private boolean isPermissionGranted(){
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                //for android 11
                return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
            } else {
                //below
                int readExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                //
                return readExternalStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            }
        }
        private void takePermission(){
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                if(!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
                       // ContextCompat.startActivity(intent, null);

                    } catch (Exception exception){
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == 100){
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                    if(Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        takePermission();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.length > 0){
            if(requestCode == 101){
                boolean write = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean read = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if(write && read){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Read Permission is Granted in android 10 and below", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{
                    takePermission();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<File> findPdf (File file) {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        //assert files != null;
        assert files != null;
        for (File singleFile : files){
            if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
                arrayList.addAll(findPdf(singleFile));
            } else {
                if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    arrayList.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
    public void displayPdf()
    {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));


        ArrayList<File> pdfList = new ArrayList<>(findPdf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
        MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, pdfList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPdfSelected(File file) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PdfActivity.class)
        .putExtra("path",file.getAbsolutePath()));
    }


}
```

'''

```
     - activity_main.xml
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/teal_200">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rv"/>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

'''

```
     - Manifest file
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.pdfreader">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.PDFReader">
            <activity
                android:name=".PdfActivity"
                android:exported="false" />
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>

'''
```

If community needs more than this please let me know. I presume that I can edit my question and add more codes if needed.
Again I am sorry if I make silly mistakes. "The man who makes mistakes is better than a man who don't try"
Thank You in Advance.

```
ERROR

--------- beginning of crash
2022-01-23 20:10:29.308 6339-6339/com.example.pdfreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pdfreader, PID: 6339
    java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.findPdf(MainActivity.java:130)
        at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.findPdf(MainActivity.java:133)
        at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.findPdf(MainActivity.java:133)
        at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.displayPdf(MainActivity.java:149)
        at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
```

Comment: "but keeps crashing on android 11" -- could you please edit your question and provide the complete stack trace of your crash?

Comment: Respected Sir/Madam,
Is this what you wanted. Edited just now could you check the end of the question, I pasted the error Sir/Madam.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Generally speaking, most apps should not be attempting to use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and most apps should not be attempting to scan all of external storage. You may be better served by using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (or `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`) to let the system provide a UI to let the user pick some PDF content for your app to use.

Comment: Yea,h Sir/Madam  thank you for clarifying my doubt. I hope I can change neseccery code.